How to call a function in a slot component from parent?
I have a component (Child) that has a slot. It also has a button that I want to trigger a function in the component in the slot (GrandChild). Is that possible? And how to achieve that? I have tried using ref on the slot, but without success. Also looked on using a scoped slot. I'm using vue3 with Typescript.
The Child does not know what component that should be in the slot, but maybe that could be sent as a prop.
<!-- Parent.vue -->

<script setup lang="ts">
    import Child from './TestSlotsChild.vue';
    import GrandChild from './TestSlotsGrandChild.vue';
</script>

<template>
    <div class="parent">
        <h2>I'm the parent</h2>
        <Child>
            <GrandChild/>
        </Child>
    </div>
</template>

<!-- Child.vue -->

<script setup lang="ts">
</script>

<template>
    <div class="child">
        <h3>I'm the child</h3>
        <slot >
        </slot>
        <button>Call myMethod in GrandChild</button>
    </div>
</template>

<!-- GrandChild.vue -->

<script setup lang="ts">
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    const called = ref(false);

    function myMethod() {
        called.value = true;
        console.log('myMethod called in grandchild component');
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div class="grandchild">
        <h4>I'm the grandchild</h4>
        <p v-if="called">Parent called <em>myMethod</em> of grandchild.</p>
    </div>
</template>

Edit: An additional issue I ran into was when I wanted to make a for loop in the parent. Then I got the following error on myMethod: "Property 'myMethod' does not exist on type '(CreateComponentPublicInstanceWithMixins<ToResolvedProps<{}, {}>, { myMethod: () => void; }, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 18 more ..., {}> | null)[]'.ts-plugin(2339)"
Is there a solution for that?
I guess I must have unique refs for each element in the array, but couldn't really get it to work.
<!-- Parent.vue -->

<script setup lang="ts">
    import { useTemplateRef, computed } from 'vue';
    import Child from './TestSlotsChild.vue';
    import GrandChild from './TestSlotsGrandChild.vue';

    const gc = useTemplateRef('grandchild');

    const someArray = computed(() => [
        {childComponent: Child,         grandChildComponent: GrandChild},
        {childComponent: Child,         grandChildComponent: GrandChild},
    ]);
</script>

<template>
    <div class="parent">
        <h2>I'm the parent</h2>

        <div v-for="(element, index) in someArray" :key="index">
            <component
                :is=element.childComponent
                @click:btn="gc?.myMethod()"
            >
                <!-- <component :is="dialog.component" ref="dialogContets2"/> -->
                <component :is="element.grandChildComponent" ref="grandchild"/>
            </component>
        </div >
    </div>
</template>



Expose the method from the GrandChild component in order to get access to it using a ref :
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

const called = ref(false);

function myMethod() {
  called.value = true;
  console.log('myMethod called in grandchild component');
}

defineExpose({
  myMethod //<--- expose it this way
})
</script>

<template>
  <div class="grandchild">
    <h4>I'm the grandchild</h4>
    <p v-if="called">Parent called <em>myMethod</em> of grandchild.</p>
  </div>
</template>


Then you can emit an event from the Child component :
<script setup lang="ts">

const emit = defineEmits(['click:btn'])

</script>

<template>
    <div class="child">
        <h3>I'm the child</h3>
        <slot>
        </slot>
        <button @click="emit('click:btn')">Call myMethod in GrandChild</button>
    </div>
</template>


Finally add a ref on the GrandChild component and call its exposed method using the emitted event from the Child component :
<script setup>
import { useTemplateRef } from 'vue';
import Child from './Child.vue';
import GrandChild from './GrandChild.vue';

const gc = useTemplateRef('grandchild')

</script>

<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <h2>I'm the parent</h2>
    <Child @click:btn="gc.myMethod()">
      <GrandChild ref="grandchild" />
    </Child>
  </div>
</template>



Thanks, that works! I just had to update to the following line in the parent, otherwise it complained that on gc that: "Object is possibly 'null'."
<Child @click:btn="gc?.myMethod()">

You're welcome, you can accept my answer if this works well for you

I will! Do you have any suggestion on the aditional issue that I added?

You can do <Child @click:btn="gc && gc.myMethod()">

Thanks, but that did not help. The issue is that "Property 'myMethod' does not exist on type..."
